# Magento 2 Uninstall or update Authorize.net module

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, upgrade, authorize.net

I wan't to know how can I uninstall Authorize.net module from Magento 2.2.7 without affecting other modules, because as far as I know it's a core module. The reason I want to do this is because Authorize.net module in Magento Marketplace seems to have **Vault** option.
Furthermore, I tried to update the composer package for a newer version: `composer require authorizenet/magento-module-authorizenet:1.0.1`

Sadly did not work because I cannot see the vault option in admin panel.
If I cannot update the module, can I delete the whole module and install the one from Market Place?

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be a core module. Can you just disable it like so?

php bin/magento module:disable -c Magento_AuthorizenetAcceptjs Magento_Authorizenet